# How can connect Golang and Android with socket.io ?

Tags: android, go, websocket, socket.io, golang-migrate

I want to send data from Android to Golang with socket.io .
I do that with Nodejs correctly But now , i want do with Go.
I cant find simple example.how can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you would like to use a Go implementation of the Socket.IO server library instead of the standard Node.js one. If so, you can try [googollee/go-socket.io project](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io). Here is an example from the project page:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func main() {
    server, err := socketio.NewServer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    server.On("connection", func(so socketio.Socket) {
        log.Println("on connection")
        so.Join("chat")
        so.On("chat message", func(msg string) {
            log.Println("emit:", so.Emit("chat message", msg))
            server.BroadcastTo("chat", "chat message", msg)
        })
        so.On("disconnection", func() {
            log.Println("on disconnect")
        })
    })
    server.On("error", func(so socketio.Socket, err error) {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    })

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./asset")))
    log.Println("Serving at localhost:5000...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil))
}
```

Comment: dear i do that . but i want to have android studio  example code.

Comment: @m-tech, googollee/go-socket.io implements the same protocol as the Node.js does, so there are no specific examples for it. So, the [standard android implementation](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) should work.